# Error in install Shopware on Centos 7

Tags: centos, composer-php, shopware

I have problem in installing Shopware on Centos 7

I have follow the documentation of setup in this link :
https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/5.3/README.md#installation-via-git

But i face an error when run this command 
`ant build-unit`

```
 [exec] The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
 [exec] The download failed repeatedly, aborting.
```

My current Composer version is 1.2.0

is this the problem that i can't continue installation

Answer (score 1):

The best way might be to download Shopware directly from the [Shopware Download Section](http://en.community.shopware.com/Downloads_cat_725.html)

Just download the latest Version, upload it to your Server, unzip it and install it.

Or just follow the [Installation Guide](http://en.community.shopware.com/_detail_1351.html)

Comment: This version will need GUI to install Shopware, i'm trying to install it by shell

Comment: Not a problem either, just use the [sw-cli-tools](https://github.com/shopwareLabs/sw-cli-tools) then.